# Outputing call stack in addition to exception name and description in java application

Tags: java

I executing a java application and I see some exception but not call stack. Can I somehow see callstack as well? It would let me better understand what is the problem.

Answer (score 2):

`printStackTrace()` or `getStackTrace()`?

Comment: can I do something similar without modifying code? It's not my jar file.

Answer (score 1):

You can call an `Exception` object's `printStackTrace()` method.

[More information here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#printStackTrace%28%29).

Answer (score 0):

```
try{
//code
}catch(Exception ex){
ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

You might consider using a logger instead

```
try{
//code
}catch(Exception ex){
LOG.warn("whatever went wrong", ex);
}
```